LWC conditional Rendering a child component and maintain visibility
I have a drop down component that will render another child component depending on the value chosen.
The component displays correctly. The issue I have since the component is in a for each loop.
When I go to the next record to select from the drop down, the first child component disappears.
How can you maintain visibility once a component is rendered visible it will never be made invisible again?
I have tried logic using a Set to track the record id value from the value of the drop down.
That didn't seem to work.
Any points would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
Vinh

Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please take a minute to read How to Ask and perhaps take the [tour] before you [edit] your question to include relevant code and template snippets. We need to see what you have tried and where you are stuck in order to help.

Please share what you have tried.
